# MongoDB database didn't save data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm tried to save my data in mongoDB, but there is a problem I have faced do not saved my data always run error condition. here is save query code:

```
blog.save((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Error",
        });
      }
      res.json(data);
    });
```

Here always run  `"error": "Error"`

I don't know why not save my data, always show  `"error": "Error"` this message in postman output.

I have tried code this way:

```
const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const Category = require("../models/category");
const Tag = require("../models/tags");
const formidable = require("formidable");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const { stripHtml } = require("string-strip-html");
const _ = require("lodash");
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");
const fs = require("fs");

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Image could not upload",
      });
    }
    const { title, body, categories, tags } = fields;

    // validation
    if (!title || !title.length) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "title is required",
      });
    }

    if (!body || body.length < 10) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Content is too short",
      });
    }

    let blog = new Blog();
    blog.title = title;
    blog.body = body;
    blog.slug = slugify(title).toLowerCase();
    blog.mtitle = `${title} | ${process.env.APP_NAME}`;
    blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));
    blog.postedBy = req.user._id;

    if (files.photo) {
      if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Image should be less then 1mb in size",
        });
      }
      blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
      blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
    }

    blog.save((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Error",
        });
      }
      res.json(data);
    });
  });
};
```

I have check my database connect is ok, also I have checked my Schema It's also ok,

I have check step by step before

```
if (!body || body.length < 10) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Content is too short",
      });
    }
```

upto this code work succesfully, but after that maybe error.

Any Suggestion Please.

Comment: Did you log the object to be created before saving

Comment: Yes, didn't show any error, also save a column name in my database but it's empty.

Comment: What was the value of `err`?

Comment: actually error was on this line `blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));` if I used `stripHtml` then show me error, if I skip `stripHtml` then everything is ok.